# can I automatically access a certain table in a website and copy the data into mine using Asp.net ?

Tags: asp.net

it's been bothering me for a while ..
I want to automatically access a certain table in a website and copy the data into mine using Asp.net like gold prices or something like that .. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to get the HTML from a URL and then parse through the pieces of interest to you, like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("SiteThatHasTable.com");

foreach(HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")) 
{
    // Do something with table name here
    table.Id

    foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr")) 
    {
        // Do something with table row here

        foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td")) 
        {
            // Do something with table cell here
            cell.InnerText
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Remove the `th` portion of the `SelectNodes` in the looping through the cells if you do not care about doing anything with the row headers.